# How can I send different audio to my left and right speakers?

Tags: pulseaudio

I've found that I can use pavucontrol to control the volume in my left and right speakers independently, by un-clicking the "lock channels together" button. However, I can't find a setting to let me send different output to the two speakers - i.e. I want to play audio track A on my left speaker and audio track B on my right speaker. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [`sox`](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html)(*Sound eXchange*); if you have two files with similar bitrates or already set to one channel:

```
play -M A.mp3 B.mp3
```

Otherwise:

```
play -m "|sox A.mp3 -p remix 0 1-2" "|sox B.mp3 -p remix 1-2 0"
```

What this does is simply `play` the output of two `sox` commands which output to pipe(`-p`); the first one remixes L/R to R and the second remixes L/R to L. If you're playing sources with different gain values etc. you may need to adjust the two `sox` commands(gain etc.).

Comment: play FAIL formats: no handler for file extension `mp3' - need libsox-fmt-mp3 as well for this.

Comment: @Benubird Maybe you need something like [libsox-fmt-all](http://superuser.com/a/421168) or something like that; are you on Ubuntu?

Comment: Also, does not work: the default functionality of -M is to play the given files in sequence, not in parallel. You can tell it to mix them, but from what I can see that doesn't actually play them on separate channels, it just plays them both on one, AND will only work if they have the same sampling rate.

Comment: I'm on ubuntu, yes. But reading the man for play seems to say that mix just plays them on top of each other.

Comment: @Benubird When you get a chance take a look; this should work. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that works, and I give you an extra +1 for the specific syntax - I've never seen the `"|` thing before.

Comment: @Benubird Thank you, it's completely exotic for me too, it feels a bit like a graph representation with "lines" connected i.e. the whole audio metaphore etc. In hindsight when I see `|program [options] ...` in the doc it makes sense but figuring it took some time at first. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

So, I found **a** solution. Turns out that if I run the media via two separate processes (i.e. "play a.mp3 &; play b.mp3") then pavucontrol will allow my to control their volume separately. I can unlock the channels, set one to 0% left, the other to 0% right, and this will work.

However, I feel like this doesn't quite answer the question - it works for my use case, but I'm not sure it will be useful to future people who come here with a similar question, who are most likely looking for a way to do it without going through the pavucontrol gui. Something that I would appreciate knowing how to do (if possible) as well.

So, I'll leave this open for more answers, and only mark this one correct if I get upvotes to indicate that other people find it helpful (or no other answers).